# Debugging Ios App Extension in Flutter app

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, debugging, ios-app-extension

I am writing a flutter application, but I needed to write a ios application extension in the native part. I think there might be a bug and I'm debugging this target. I selected the extension I needed as a target for launching, made a debug scheme for it, selected the application with which the extension would be launched, and launched it. Next I got an error about not being able to run flutter without a debugger:

`To launch in debug mode in iOS 14+, run flutter run from Flutter tools, run from an IDE with a Flutter IDE plugin or run the iOS project from Xcode. Alternatively profile and release mode apps can be launched from the home screen.`

Is there any way to debug ios extensions for flutter app?

Comment: You can probably just build and run the extension from Xcode directly.  You don't say what sort of extension you are working on, but some extensions can't be launched directly (e.g. A "Share" extension is launched by iOS when the user selects it from a share sheet). In this case use the Xcode Debug menu option "Attach to process by PID or name..." and enter your extension's Bundle ID.  The debugger will attach once the extension is launched.

Comment: I am working with NotificationServiceExtension and NotificationContentExtension. When I launch the extension, a window opens for me "choose an application to launch"
I choose my Containing App which is written in flutter and I am getting the error I posted above.

Comment: Yes. Best not to do that. Use the debugger menu to attach the process by name and then send a notification to trigger your extension.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot! Can you please explain why my debug option is bad?

Comment: It's to do with the way that flutter debugging runs the app in order to support hot reloading. The app on the device communicates with a process on your Mac. When you ask Xcode to launch your app to support your extension, it doesn't start this flutter process.  It will crash the same way it will crash if you tap on a dev build on your device rather than running it from flutter